# Did prophet Muhammad do this

Tags: hadith, prophet-muhammad

I saw a hadith about prophet Muhammad being intimate with his concubine, Maria, in his wife Hafsa’s bed. When she saw this he told her not to tell Aisha about it and that he wouldn’t go near Maria again. Is this true and why would he not want Aisha to know about it if it was permissible for him to be with Maria? Also, why would he choose do this on Hafsa’s day and on her bed? Can someone please shed some light on this

https://www.altafsir.com/Tafasir.asp?tMadhNo=0&tTafsirNo=73&tSoraNo=66&tAyahNo=3&tDisplay=yes&UserProfile=0&LanguageId=2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is simply not authentic. How can we justify what is not authentic?

Comment: This incident is authentic! It is in [Sahih Bukhari 2468](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:2468), [Nisai 3959](https://sunnah.com/nasai:3959), [Tafsir Ibn Abbas 66:1](https://www.altafsir.com/Tafasir.asp?tMadhNo=0&tTafsirNo=73&tSoraNo=66&tAyahNo=1&tDisplay=yes&UserProfile=0&LanguageId=2), [Tafsir Jalalyn 66:1](https://www.altafsir.com/Tafasir.asp?tMadhNo=0&tTafsirNo=74&tSoraNo=66&tAyahNo=1&tDisplay=yes&UserProfile=0&LanguageId=2), and Tafsir Tabari 66:1!

Comment: Nothing like that in the first reference you have given.